# Server side pagination with tablesorter

Tags: tablesorter

Is server side pagination possible with tablesorter's pager plugin? It looks like the default options require you to load all your rows into browser's memory at once. Since I have so many records this isn't really possible, I would prefer to load one page at a time. Does the tablesorter pager plugin support this? If so, what am I missing, because the documentation shows this example:

```
// process ajax so that the data object is returned along with the total number of rows
    // example: { "data" : [{ "ID": 1, "Name": "Foo", "Last": "Bar" }], "total_rows" : 100 }
    ajaxProcessing: function(ajax){
      if (ajax && ajax.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
        // return [ "data", "total_rows" ];
        return [ ajax.data, ajax.total_rows ];
      }
    },
```

That, and other examples I've been able to find, look like it loads all rows at once into memory in the ajax processing function.

http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html

**Update:**

After seeing the AJAX pager at http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html I have a few questions still:

1. sortList = [[2,0],[3,0]]. In the Ajax URL, do I do the conversion to the real format of &col[2]=0&col[3]=0 myself?
2. The documentation for the ajaxProcessing says:

   process ajax so that the following information is returned:
   // [ total_rows (number), rows (array of arrays), headers (array; optional) ]

It looks like total_rows is the number of rows in the database, not the number of rows in the browser memory or shown in the table. Is that correct? Next question: I understand the format of the "rows" array of arrays. But which rows are actually supposed to be in it? The documentation says it's "all rows" but is it just the current page of rows that is being displayed in the table? Is it all of the rows that the user has paged through thus far? I assume it isn't all of the rows that are in the DB because that would ruin the point entirely.

Comment: Did you see the ajax demo? http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html

Comment: @Mottie Please see my edit. Thanks for your advice. I will of course work through the issue as the day goes by but some reassurance would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include the sort column and direction just include the server side variable `col` in the example within the url template:

```
ajaxUrl : "http:/mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}&{filterList:fcol}",
```

The `{page}` is the current page the user is viewing and `{size}` is the number of rows to show in the browser.

Include `&{sortList:col}` (with `col` matching the server side variable for sort column and direction) to include sorting. And include `&{filterLost:fcol}` (with `fcol` matching the server side varibale for filtering columns) to include any filtering. The pager plugin formats the string into `&col[2]=0&col[3]=0` (or whatever) for you.

If you look at the `ajaxProcessing` function, all it does is reformat the ajax data from your server of the **current set of rows** to display (not all rows) to match this required format:

```
// process ajax so that the following information is returned:
// [ total_rows (number), rows (array of arrays), headers (array; optional) ]
// example:
[
  100,  // total rows
  [
    [ "row1cell1", "row1cell2", ... "row1cellN" ],
    [ "row2cell1", "row2cell2", ... "row2cellN" ],
    ...
    [ "rowNcell1", "rowNcell2", ... "rowNcellN" ]
  ],
  [ "header1", "header2", ... "headerN" ] // optional
]
```

If you have an indeterminate number of rows in your database, just return `0`... it *should* still work, but then the `totalPages` and `totalRows` variables will be inaccurate.

Comment: Your documentation is misleading, it says 100, then an array of arrays for data, then an array for header. But in fact I just did hours of debugging and it has to be like this: " {"headers":["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX"],"total_rows":19,"rows":[["data1","data2","data3","data4","data5","data6"]]}" so it actually has to SAY the word rows and so on. Add that to your example maybe? Also, it's ignoring my "headers" and not replacing the header text... do you know why that is?

Comment: If you are using the same `ajaxProcessing` function, then change `"headers"` to `"col"`. There is a difference between the JSON which is the format you shared in the last comment ([see that demo's JSON](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/assets/City0.json)) and what is returned by the `ajaxProcessing` function (code shown in my answer above).

Comment: Thanks Mottie. I guess I got confused because from reading the documentation, it looked like my server was supposed to return the data in the format I mentioned earlier. I will changed "headers" to "cols" as you said. I got everything else working already, besides the sorting, but I will leave the ajaxUrl as "page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}", and then see what it gets translated to on the server. I really appreciate your patient help.

Comment: this killed a few hours of my day as well.

Comment: @JeffBorden Could you share any suggestions on how to improve the documentation for prosperity? :P

Comment: @Mottie was just thinking about pinging you.  You're a bit of a rockstar in my world as I'm a big fan of tablesorter.  The <code> blocks on this page (http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html) were missing the property names for the JSON definition.  I spent awhile converting my serialized object into a jagged array to exclude any property names - only to fail.  Finally looked at the exact JSON your demo was pulling from the server to get the actual JSON property names.  Question for you:  does ajaxProcessing have an ajaxProcessingComplete method or anything similar?

Comment: @Mottie I'm loading a tablesorter page via ajax on a sub jquery ui tab and am having issues w/ zebrastriping to work.  Since I'm loading it via ajax, I can't call it before I call the .tabs() method per your suggestions on other similar topics.

Comment: You should be able to format your JSON any way you want. The `ajaxProcessing` function is meant to take that format and convert it into something the plugin can use... There isn't any ajaxProcessingComplete method but you should be able to bind to the `pagerInitialized` event (for the initial ajax call only), but I can add something, no problem. As for zebra striping, it only works when the table rows are visible. Try [the code from here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/224#issuecomment-13086515).

Comment: Mottie see my first comment on this post. Your description of the JSON required in the documentation is not quite right and I think that's what @Jeff Border was saying. It would be clarified if you add the words "headers", "total_rows", and "rows" to the example itself. I'm speaking about the same example you posted in this post. Anyway, I did eventually get it working and I'm very grateful for the hours you saved me overall.